# TableLayoutPanel is autoscrolling to the top when contents resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running into a strange issue with a **TableLayoutPanel**. Whenever the contents in the table resize themselves minimize button to shrink to just the title), the scrollbar will automatically scroll to the top of the **TableLayoutPanel**. How can I prevent this?

**AutoSize** is set to **true** (so the form will continue to expand for new rows 
**AutoScroll** has been tested on both **true** and **false**. I now have them both as **false**.

The control that resizes has a little box that is clicked. When the box is clicked, it sets **Visible** to **False** on the main control panel (**FlowLayoutPanel**) below the header.

I **do not** want the **TableLayoutPanel** to scroll itself back to the top, I just want it to maintain its current scroll. What am I doing wrong here?

edit: fixed the typos. Too early :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up resolving this by calling **Focus** on the control prior to hiding the contents.